# Communicating with a Blackstar ID Core Guitar Amplifier through its USB Entrance and C++

Tags: c++, usb

I currently own a Blackstar ID Core 10w Amp. It has a lot of built in guitar effects such as Reverb, Delay and Modulation, all of which have various depths and levels. By connecting a USB cable from the amp to my computer, I'm able to use Blackstar's Insider software, which allows me to save these effects settings and switch to any of them with just a double click. However, the need for a double click makes it impossible for you to play your guitar and change effects during a song (which is what a pedal does).

However, I wanted to know if it's possible to use C++ to do something more ambitious than the manufacturer allows: I wanted to create a software that would play a backing track (voice+drums but no guitar) of a song and allow the user to set where during that song he wants his effects changed, and to what. This way, one would be able to play a song from start to end, not needing to worry about having to change effects.

This would also be a school project, so it can't really be a "mouse manager" or anything of this sort. It would need to be something more robust.

FYI, as far as I'm concerned, Blackstar does not give us any API we could work with. So I'd like to know if this project is even possible and, if so, where I should start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This existing project is likely to help provide clues for you to reverse engineer what Insider does and rewrite that in C++.

https://github.com/jonathanunderwood/outsider

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain regarding Blackstar's awful Insider software.

To answer your question, is this project even possible, of course it is, the Insider software obviously is able to control the amp via USB. You just have to figure out what its protocol is.

You can use a USB sniffer like [this one](https://www.virtual-serial-port.org/products/usb-sniffer/) to see what commands Insider sends to the amp when you perform actions. With enough experimentation you should be able to reverse-engineer the protocol.

It's probably easier than you think. As evidence I offer the Insider software itself, which is not very sophisticated. The settings are probably modeled more or less as a struct.